# How do I sort a multidimensional array depending on it's items array keys and values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of permissions:

```
array(
  array( "controller" => "somewhere", "action" => "",      "namespace" => "admin", "method" => "GET" ), 
  array( "controller" => "somewhere", "action" => "index", "namespace" => "admin", "method" => "" ),
  array( "controller" => "somewhere", "action" => "index", "namespace" => "admin", "method" => "GET" )
)
```

That I need to sort, so that the most "specific" one is listed first. Weather or not it's specific is determined by its relevance to the currently loaded controller, action and namespace.

**Firstly**: The three arrays' controllers cover the same area, but their actions doesn't. So the ones with a specific action should be sorted above those without.

**Secondly**: They share the same namespace, but not the same method. So the ones with a specific method should be sorted above those without.

If you have any ideas, or have any questions that needs explenations, please ask me. I would really appreciate being able to sort this array, so I don't have to redo my architecture for the permissions.

// Emil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort arrays into multidimensional array by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904718/sort-arrays-into-multidimensional-array-by-key) and [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php) and [PHP sort multidimensional array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value) and [a myriad others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sort+multidimensional+array+php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define these two functions:

```
function specific_sort($a, $b) {
    $r = more_specific($a, $b, 'controller');
    if ($r == 0) {
        $r = more_specific($a, $b, 'action');
        if ($r == 0) {
            $r = more_specific($a, $b, 'method');
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

function more_specific($a, $b, $key) {
    if (empty($a[$key])) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (empty($b[$key])) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then:

```
$rt = array(
  array( "controller" => "somewhere", "action" => "",      "namespace" => "admin", "method" => "GET" ),
  array( "controller" => "somewhere", "action" => "index", "namespace" => "admin", "method" => "" ),
  array( "controller" => "somewhere", "action" => "index", "namespace" => "admin", "method" => "GET" )
);
usort($rt, 'specific_sort');
print '<pre>';
print_r($rt);
print '</pre>';
```

It should print out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [controller] => somewhere
            [action] => index
            [namespace] => admin
            [method] => GET
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [controller] => somewhere
            [action] => index
            [namespace] => admin
            [method] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [controller] => somewhere
            [action] => 
            [namespace] => admin
            [method] => GET
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you. I came to the same conclusion, but where hoping for something that was already build into the php core (or some plugin).