# How can I sort multidimensional array through key

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Car
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [name] => Volvo
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [name] => Mercedes-Benz
                        )

                )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Manga
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [name] => Naruto
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [name] => Hunter X Hunter
                        )

                )

        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => aa
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )



)
```

Guys I want to sort the values of this array, i want to sort it by key and the key is 'name'. This should sort the first level and the second level thru key 'name'.

This array i put in `print_r()` so it looks like this. The array is not fix so i can add in the future.

So after sorting the final value of the array is...

```
Array
(

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => aa
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Car
            [children] => Array
                (
            [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [name] => Mercedes-Benz
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [name] => Volvo
                        )

            )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Manga
            [children] => Array
                (
            [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [name] => Hunter X Hunter
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [name] => Naruto
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

And this is the array in code.

```
$categories = array(
                12 => 
                    array('id' =>12, 
                              'name' => 'Car',
                                       'children' => 
                                        array(
                                            array('id' => 14,
                                                      'name' => 'volvo'
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                            array('id' => 15,
                                                      'name' => 'Mercedez-Benz'
                                            )
                                        )
                            ),

                13 => 
                    array('id' =>13, 
                              'name' => 'Manga',
                                       'children' => 
                                        array(
                                            array('id' => 16,
                                                      'name' => 'Naruto'
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                            array('id' => 17,
                                                      'name' => 'Hunter X Hunter'
                                            )
                                        )
                            ),

                18=>
                    array('id' => 18, 
                              'name'=> 'aa', 
                                      'children' => array())


                );

echo "<pre>";

print_r($categories);
```

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php and save the the data in a new vector.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort arrays into multidimensional array by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904718/sort-arrays-into-multidimensional-array-by-key)

Answer (score 0):

the 'name' is not your real 'Key', just saying, because 'key' in Php normally means the name of your array, like '18' and '12' in your array and so on, like this:

```
<?php
    $fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
    ksort($fruits);
    foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
        echo "$key = $val\n";
    }
?>
```

in this example, the result will be:

```
a = orange
b = banana
c = apple
d = lemon
```

anyway to answer your question on how to sort it on 'name', use 'usort':

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
   return $a['name'] - $b['name'];
}

usort($arr,"cmp");
```

check out the following link for further information: 
[How do I sort a PHP array by an element nested inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701855/how-do-i-sort-a-php-array-by-an-element-nested-inside)

Comment: so if its not called a key then in you example "d"=>"lemon"... what is d?

Comment: yeh you are sorting by key in the first example.  I think he wants to sort by value, where the key = `name`

Comment: @Bananam00n no in `"d"=>"lemon"`, `d` is the key and `lemon` is the value

Comment: @NappingRabbit that's exactly what I ment, but I typed it wrong sorry, deleted the comment since editing wasn't allowed :-)

Comment: what i want is to sort the value of the key

Comment: then my answer should be able to help you. with the usort, you can sort on the value of the key.

Answer (score 0):

if using php 5.3+ you can use closures in your code and sort like this

```
usort($categories,function($a,$b){
    return $a['name'] - $b['name']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So,

I'm going to try and explain it better to you

your array is big, yes, but you want to sort only on the key value '[name]'.
In my test I used the array you provided:

```
$categories = array(
            12 => 
                array('id' =>12, 
                          'name' => 'Car',
                                   'children' => 
                                    array(
                                        array('id' => 14,
                                                  'name' => 'volvo'
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        array('id' => 15,
                                                  'name' => 'Mercedez-Benz'
                                        )
                                    )
                        ),

            13 => 
                array('id' =>13, 
                          'name' => 'Manga',
                                   'children' => 
                                    array(
                                        array('id' => 16,
                                                  'name' => 'Naruto'
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        array('id' => 17,
                                                  'name' => 'Hunter X Hunter'
                                        )
                                    )
                        ),

            18=>
                array('id' => 18, 
                          'name'=> 'aa', 
                                  'children' => array())


            );
```

if the array is declared, you can add the usort like this:

```
usort($categories,"sortByName");
```

the first element in the above ($categories), is your array, the second element will provide the name of a function, in this case 'sortByName'.

after that, you just add a function into your code (it doesn't really matter where you put it, even if it's at the bottom of the page):

```
function sortByName($categories, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($categories["name"], $b["name"]);
}
```

Basically what this function does, is compairing your array with ...your array :) so it can sort it alfabetically by name- like you want it.
sthe 'strcasecmp' is to compare your strings against eachother to sort it. not that this is case non sensitive (strcmp will be case sensitive too). I assume you don't want it to check on uppercase and so on too, otherwise the result won't be what you wanted.

when you added that code, you can just print your array again:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($categories);
```

your result will be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 18
        [name] => aa
        [children] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [name] => Car
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14
                        [name] => volvo
                    )

            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 15
                        [name] => Mercedez-Benz
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
        [name] => Manga
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 16
                        [name] => Naruto
                    )

            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 17
                        [name] => Hunter X Hunter
                    )

            )

    )
```

I hope this is what you wanted. :-)

Comment: yes i know how your code works, but how can i also sort the second level of the array like sort Hunter X Hunter and Naruto

Comment: foreach($categories as $k => $v){
 foreach($v as $keyv => $valuev) {
  
  if ($keyv == "children") {
   usort($valuev,"sortByName");
   ";
   print_r($valuev );
   
  }
 }
}